# Solr (Sunspot), max results more than 30?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr

I'm using Solr via Sunspot for rails, but I can't figure out how to return more than 30 results?

Say I have this block for search:

```
posts = Post.search do
  keywords('something')
end
```

How would I establish that sunspot should return *all* of the matches, not just 30?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `paginate`:

```
posts = Post.search do
  keywords 'something'
  paginate :page => 1, :per_page => 100
end
```

To change the default number of results add the following to `application.rb` or its own initializer file.

```
Sunspot.config.pagination.default_per_page = 30
```

[Source](https://github.com/outoftime/sunspot/wiki/Ordering-and-pagination)

Answer (score 5):

To clarify, Solr *always* paginates results -- 30 is an arbitrary default, but there is always a page length. If you want all the results, you can either set a very high page length, or page through the results in your code to compose an array with all the results (the latter probably being preferable).

Comment: Lame! Why doesn't the result set have a method like "next" that does this for us? T.T;

Answer (score 1):

You can also modify your solr configuration as stated here: http://solr.pl/en/2011/01/10/optimization-query-result-window-size/