# Sunspot solr search, how to return all records at once?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails

I am using solr via sunspot in my rails application where I need to return more than 30 records which is set by default. I can do it as told in 
[Sunspot solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811398/solr-sunspot-max-results-more-than-30) but i don't want pagination for the data. I want to display all the data in a single page irrespective of rows. Also providing a hard coded value is not a probable solution which I'm looking for.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Solr always paginates, so it looks like there's no way to disable pagination through Sunspot (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ruby-sunspot/kVKfsrDpokc). The only thing I can think to do is get the number of records for your model before the search, and then set the per_page variable to that number so you're guaranteed to only return one page. Something like this:

```
count = Service.count
@search = Service.search do 
    keywords(params[:search])
    paginate :page => 1, :per_page => count
end
```

Comment: yaa .. i had thought the same and kept the option for last but had to implement as could not get any other soln.

Comment: be careful. yet `per_page: 10**10` gives an error (exceeding maximum, i guess), so it is possible to use static `per_page: 10**9` for example instead of `Service.count` each time

Comment: Execute twice  the query Service.search(....).total and pass the total as per page argument